# SSRS lookup with datediff Incorrect result error showing in fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have to write again this problem. I am not an expert in SSRS.
I have been trying to resolve this issue. Even though the fields are all the same datatype am still getting error and incorrect time difference in the filed in some fields. 
I do not know what am doing wrong. This is the code.  Please find below screen shot also.

```
enter code =Datediff(DateInterval.Minute, Fields!health_start_date.Value, Lookup(Fields!flight_date.Value & Fields!register_number.Value &  DATEPART(DateInterval.Hour,Fields!health_start_date.Value) , Fields!FL_DATE.Value & Fields!REG.Value & DatePart(DateInterval.Hour, Fields!ATD.Value), Fields!ATD.Value, "DataSetAIMS") ) MOD 60 & " mins "
```

here

The scenario is that the two fields Health start date and ATD have two different dataset which shows time of flight differently but the time difference is always in minutes. What am trying to do is to  compare the two table with their hour and date using lookup to find difference in minutes [image: This is the first dataset table]

[image: This is DataSetAIMS table]

Comment: And what are the values of `Fields!health_start_date.Value` and `Fields!ATD.Value` when there is an error? Why have you tagged `pregresql` too? That has nothing to do with SQL Server and SSRS.

Comment: ATD is time ( hh:mm  eg 13:30)  and health start date is ddmmyyyy eg 02052018 format. I have to compare two dataset from two different sources one from Postgresql and one from SQL.

Comment: OK, but what the the **specific** values when the error occurs?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by the specific values. The fileds only have #error.  the error occurs on few fields and other fields are working okay.  eg health_start_date.Value = 04042018 ATD = 01:20

Comment: Not sure how more specific I can really be here... I'm asking, when you get the value `#error` for your expression `=CStr(DATEDIFF("n", Fields!health_start_date.Value, Lookup(Fields!health_start_date.Value,  Fields!ATD.Value, Fields!ATD.Value, "DataSetAIMS")) MOD 60 & " mins ")` what is the value of `Fields!ATD.Value` and `Fields!health_start_date.Value` within that expression (when it produces an error).

Comment: At the moment, all I have to work on is something along the lines of *"I get an error sometimes for my expression `=Fields!MyColumn1.Value / Fields!MyColumn2.Value`. Why?"* Without knowing the values for `Column1` and `Column2`, could you answer that question?

Comment: health_start_date.Value= 16:47  Fields!ATD.Value = 17:00

Comment: Apologies. Trying to connect to see my work :  health_start_date.Value= 16:47 Fields!ATD.Value = 17:00  That is one of the value in the field before it produces error

Comment: It sounds like you're asking it to find the value 16:47 in DataSetAIMS and it isn't finding it because it's 17:00, not 16:47. I.e., I think the issue is in your Lookup function, not the DateDiff function.

Comment: @Russel I have explained again for you to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I see the problem: you're really close and this stuff trips us all up on occasion. In the LOOKUP function, I think you are joining the two data sets based on:

- flight_date = FL_DATE, and
- register_number = REG, and
- HOUR(health_start_date) = HOUR(ATD)

Which is fine, but the ampersand (&) just "concatenates" strings together, and (a) your strings don't actually match, and (b) HOUR is a number, not a string.

(a) The "date" in the first data set is DDMMYYYY, and in the 2nd it is DDMMYY. I.e., "05222018" is not the same as "052818", so your lookup will not work. It's possible that they are stored correctly as date fields in the database and so the comparison will work fine, but better to force them to match. For that I'd recommend formatting each of the date strings into a standard format, like "FormatDateTime(Fields!flight_date.Value, DateFormat.VBShortDate)".

(b) Should be easy, just add ".ToString" after the parentheses, like "DATEPART(DateInterval.Hour,Fields!health_start_date.Value).ToString()".

(c) I'm assuming the register_number and REG are formatted the same.

Given all that, your new LOOKUP function might look something like this:

```
=Datediff(DateInterval.Minute, 
    Fields!health_start_date.Value, 
    Lookup(
        FormatDateTime(Fields!flight_date.Value, DateFormat.VBShortDate) & Fields!register_number.Value &  DATEPART(DateInterval.Hour,Fields!health_start_date.Value).ToString() , 
        FormatDateTime(Fields!FL_DATE.Value, DateFormat.VBShortDate) & Fields!REG.Value & DatePart(DateInterval.Hour, Fields!ATD.Value).ToString()
        , Fields!ATD.Value
        , "DataSetAIMS") 
        ).ToString() & " minutes"
```

However, I think you'd make your life easier by just doing that sort of calculation in the database layer, in the report query, something like:

```
SELECT 
    d1.FlightDate
    , d1.RegisterNumber
    , d1.HealthStartDate
    , d2.ATD
    , DiffInMinutes = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, d1.HealthStartDate, d2.ATD)
FROM DataSet1 d1
    JOIN DataSetAIMS d2
        ON CAST(d1.FlightDate AS DATE) = CAST(d2.FL_DATE AS DATE)
        AND d1.register_number = d2.REG
        AND DATEPART(HOUR, d1.health_start_date) = DATEPART(HOUR, d2.ATD)
```

This code certainly isn't exact, but hopefully it will get you pointed in the right direction!

Comment: Hi Russel, Thanks for explanation. I made a mistake in the screen shot. The flight_date was actually as ddmmyyyy, I just realised now. But I try this now the code for lookup  but it is still showing error in all the field.

Comment: I forgot the ToString on the HOURS function, edited above. Try that. Otherwise, is it giving any specific error?

Comment: It is still giving error#. I am using this code based on  the flight_date and FL_date are in the same format ddMMyy,

Comment: Let's try testing your join condition: take out the big function you have for this field and just put in one of the concatenations to see what comes up, if anything: "=FormatDateTime(Fields!flight_date.Value, DateFormat.VBShortDate) & Fields!register_number.Value &  DATEPART(DateInterval.Hour,Fields!health_start_date.Value).ToString()"

Comment: something comes up eg    3/14/2018G-EME16   The number match the hour and date match as well and the register number, but are all joined together

Comment: I noticed that Fields!FL_DATE.Value is underlined with red might be an issue because in the expression code FormatDateTime(Fields!FL_DATE.Value is not within the current datasets. not sure how someone can implement this code inside that field from another datasets

Comment: Yep, the string "3/14/2018G-EME16" is because of the ampersand (&) which just sticks the strings together. For the missing field, there's really no way around that.

Comment: Do you think no way around this. I might have to give up. Thanks for your time. learn so much

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Russel. I have accepted your answer. What I did was to remove the formatdate from the expression code and modify the query design code to convert to the same time date :  the code below

`=Datediff(DateInterval.Minute, Fields!health_start_date.Value, Lookup(Fields!register_number.Value &  DATEPART(DateInterval.Hour,Fields!health_start_date.Value).ToString() , Fields!REG.Value & DatePart(DateInterval.Hour, Fields!ATD.Value).ToString(), Fields!ATD.Value, "DataSetAIMS") ).ToString()  MOD 60 & " mins "`

or the below as well works :

```
=Datediff(DateInterval.Minute, 
Fields!health_start_date.Value, 
Lookup(
    Format(Fields!flight_date.Value, "ddMMyy") & Fields!register_number.Value &  DATEPART(DateInterval.Hour,Fields!health_start_date.Value).ToString() , 
    Format(Fields!FL_DATE.Value, "ddMMyy") & Fields!REG.Value & DatePart(DateInterval.Hour,Fields!ATD.Value).ToString()
    , Fields!ATD.Value
    , "DataSetAIMS") 
    ).ToString()  MOD 60 & " minutes
```